# Why does (?:...) regex behave differently for re.match and re.findall?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-greedy

I was working on a CS50 problem where you have to find consecutively repeating pattern of strings (nucleotides in a DNA sequence). I figured I'd use `re` since it's Python3 assignment and I've tinkered it with a little bit before and thought I could figure it out... but nope.

So I searched how I could accomplish this and found a topic where a user suggested using `re.findall("(?:<pattern>)+", <string>)` and it was exactly what I needed to solve the problem.

So I got curious about the `?:` expression and looked up the documentation but couldn't understand what it meant by a `non-capturing group` and, again, had to look around for an answer when I found an explanation using a string composed of a web address.

In this specific example the user was using `re.match`:

```
"(?:https?|ftp)://(stackoverflow.com)"

output:
    group1: (stackoverflow.com)
vs

"(https?|ftp)://(stackoverflow.com)"

output:
    group1: (https)
    group2: (stackoverflow.com)
```

At this point I understood what non-capturing meant... but now I did not understand why `?:` behaved differently for `re.match` and `re.findall`, where the match object, as described in the official documentation, does not capture the indicated group while the returned list from `re.findall` method *seemingly* capturing the matching substring *and* grouping consecutive repetitions as one.

My best guess is that since it's non-capturing the method continues to find matching substrings consecutively and once it ends it "closes" the group and that is why the repeated substrings are grouped as one. But I still don't know why `re.findall` returns what is not supposed to be captured and if someone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions — anyway, the question would be more clear with a minimal SSCCE about just the behavior in question, with output *for all relevant example cases*. (The statement about “closes the group” sounds inaccurate.)

Answer (score 2):

A 'capturing group' in regex is normally denoted by parentheses. In a regex like this:

```
<before>(<capture>)<after>
```

the 'capturing group' is `(<capture>)`, and it means that this is *the part of the string that we actually want* - the rest of the regex is meant to target that. We need this for capturing, say, "numbers followed by the word 'dollar'":

```
(\d+)\s*dollar
```

---

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) returns a `Match` object, which has several 'groups' you can access with the `.group(n)` method.

- Group 0 always contains *the entire matched string, regardless of any 'match groups' within it*. In the above example, matched against the string `"35 dollar item"`, it would be `"35 dollar".
- Group `n > 0` contains *the nth capture group in the regex*. In the above example, matched against the string `"35 dollar item"`, it would be simply `"35"`.

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) has behavior that differs based on the number of capturing groups in the regex:

- if there are no capturing groups, return a list of all strings matching the entire regex (e.g. `.group(0)`)
- if there is exactly one capturing group, return a list of all strings matching just that capturing group (e.g. `.group(1)`)
- if there is more than one capturing group, return a list of tuples of `(.group(1), .group(2), ..., .group(n))`.

---

The idea of a non-capturing group is that sometimes we want to use expressions that require parentheses to disambiguate them. Most commonly, `|`. For example, if I wanted to capture the surname (but not the title) of someone addressed by "Mr." or "Ms.", I might write a regex like so:

```
(?:Mr|Ms)\.\s*(\w+)
```

`(?:Mr|Ms)` is a non-capturing group, so it *won't be treated as its own group* (e.g. `.group(1)`). Meanwhile, `(\w+)` is a capturing group, so it *will* be treated as its own group. From there, we can observe the behaviors of `re.match()` and `re.findall()`, and see that they're consistent with their documentation:

```
>>> regex = r'(?:Mr|Ms)\.\s*(\w+)'
>>> mo = re.match(regex, 'Mr. Big and Ms. Small')
>>> mo.group(0)
'Mr. Big'
>>> mo.group(1)
'Big'
>>> re.findall(regex, 'Mr. Big and Ms. Small')
['Big', 'Small']
```

Because there's only one capture group, `re.findall()` ignores group 0.

Contrast behavior of the following, which would register `Mr` and `Ms` as capture groups, and thus produce different output (since now there's more than one capture group, so `re.findall()` changes its output format:

```
>>> regex2 = r'(Mr|Ms)\.\s*(\w+)'  # omitting the ?:
>>> re.findall(regex2, 'Mr. Big and Ms. Small')
[('Mr', 'Big'), ('Ms', 'Small')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in composing this answer! I'm still not sure why, though, using `?:` with `findall` captures all consecutive repetitions of a pattern and, if you're knowledgeable of why, I'd be grateful for a brief explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: Specifically, `(?:)` means you want to use the syntactic benefits of parentheses, without actually making a capture group that'll muck up the rest of your regex. See the edit for contrasting the effects of without the `?:`. As for why `findall` captures all occurrences of the pattern - that's literally the point of why it exists. It's "find **all**", not "find the first",  or "find at start of string" (which is what `.match()` does`

Comment: I think I understand it now, thank you very much. So since `:?` doesn't capture, all the pattern that fit the regex are being "piled" into one until the continuity is broken is how I'm understanding it.